# Add custom abbreviation format for cells using AXLSX gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, axlsx, caxlsx

I am using the `caxlsx` gem to export some data and I need to add custom abbreviation formatting for cells on a specific column to add units of T(trillions), B(billions), and M(millions) to the end. So:

- 27 -> 27M
- 1555.5 -> 1.56B
- 1232567 -> 1.23T

I tried doing:

```
workbook = Axlsx::Workbook.new
sheet = workbook.add_worksheet
abbr = workbook.styles.add_style(format_code: '[>=1000000]0.0,,,"T";[>=1000]0.0,,"B";0"M"') #works in custom format when explicitly setting in excel
```

which sends the data back and does download but when trying to open the file, it gives me `We found a problem with some content in...`

I've been at this for hours and can't seem to find a way. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Your format seems a bit off. Can you try: `'[>=1000000].00,,"T";[>=1000].00,"B";0.00"M"'`

Comment: @engineersmnky I tried that but to no avail. Still gives me the `We found a problem with some content in..`